# Using Logistic Regression in Mahout

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, regression, mahout, logistic-regression

I have about 11000 rows of data in a CSV file which contains column Text and Class. Text is twitter message and each of them is assigned with a True or false in Class. I used these two commands to train and test this data using logistic regression model but the result is not good with AUC 0.52. I don't quite understand some parameters like `--rate` `--features` and `--lambda` so can somebody help me with more appropriate commands? Thanks a lot!

```
$ bin/mahout trainLogistic --passes 100 --rate 50 --lambda 0.001 --input twitter.csv --features 10000 --output twitter.model --target Class --categories 2 --predictors Text --types t

$ bin/mahout runlogistic --input twitter.csv --model twitter.model --AUC --confusion
```

The link of data file : [twitter.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dd65nn4q5shvpq3/twitter.csv)

Comment: `mashout`? LOL. No wonder it doesn't work, it seems you mashed up something. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the parameters used to train the model.

```
"input" : training data
"output" : path to the file where model will be written.
"target" : dependent variable which is to be predicted
"categories" : number of unique possible values that target can be assigned
"predictors" : list of field names that are to be used to predict target variable
"types" : datatypes for the items in predictor list
"passes" : number of passes over the input data
"features" : size of internal feature vector
"lambda" : amount of co-efficient decay to use
"rate" : initial learning rate
```

You can refer the [Logistic Regression in Mahout](http://nishutayaltech.blogspot.in/2013/10/logistic-regression-in-mahout.html) post for detailed description.